# PHP no abre una dirección que tengo

Tags: php

vengo a pedir su ayuda, tengo un problema y es que al usar header en PHP, no reconoce la dirección a la que quiero llegar pero si acceso poniendo la dirección manualmente en el navegador si entra, adjunto mi código para que puedan observar, creo que es por el manejo de sesiones pero no logro encontrar el problema.

**Primero está el index.php**

```
<?php 

include_once 'includes/user.php';
include_once 'includes/user_session.php';

$userSession = new UserSession();
$user = new User();

if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    $user->setUser($userSession->getCurrentUser());
}
else if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $userForm = $_POST['username'];
    $passForm = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->userExists($userForm, $passForm))
    {
        $userSession->setCurrentUser($userForm);
        $user->setUser($userForm);

        if($user->getRol() == 'po')
        {
            include_once 'vistas/home.php';
        }
        else
        {
            include_once 'vistas/homeAdmin.php';
        }

        
    }
    else
    {
        $errorLogin = "Datos Incorrectos";
        include_once 'vistas/login.php';
    }
}
else
{
    include_once 'vistas/login.php';
}
```

?>

**Si el usuario ingresa bien sus credenciales entonces pasa al home.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Registro de Frente</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>
   
    
    <div class="limiter">

        <div class="container-login100">

            <div class="" style="background: white; border-radius: 12px; padding: 10px;">

                <div style="align-content:center;">
                     <?php 
                    echo "Bienvenido"." ".$user->getUser().", Puedes iniciar o continuar tu trámite donde lo dejaste <br>";
                     ?>
                     <?php 
                    echo "No olvides: "."<a class='btn-light' href='includes/logout.php'>Cerrar Session</a>"." cuando termines"."<br>";
                     ?>

                </div>
                <br>
                     <?php 
                     include "motor.php";
                        
                    
                      ?>

                    
                       

                
            </div>


        </div>
            
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Como pueden ver, este incluye a motor.php**

```
    <html>
<?php 

    $codFlujo = $_GET['codflujo'];
    $codProceso = $_GET['codproceso'];

    include_once 'conexion.inc.php';
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM flujo WHERE CodFlujo = '$codFlujo' AND CodProceso = '$codProceso'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $codProcesoSiguiente = $fila['CodProcesoSiguiente'];
    $archivo = $fila['Pantalla'];
 ?>
<body>
    <h1>Inscripciones CEI</h1>
    <br>

    <form action="../controlador.php" method="GET">
        <?php
        include $archivo;
        ?>

        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $codFlujo; ?>" name="codflujo">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $codProceso; ?>" name="codproceso">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $codProcesoSiguiente; ?>" name="codprocesosiguiente">
        <input type="submit" value="Anterior" name="Anterior">
        <input type="submit" value="Siguiente" name="Siguiente">
    </form>

</body>
 </html>
```

**Cuando se pulsa el botón de siguiente, se dirige a controlador.php**

```
<?php 

    $codFlujo = $_GET['codflujo'];
    $codProceso = $_GET['codproceso'];
    $codProcesoSiguiente = $_GET['codprocesosiguiente'];

    if(isset($_GET['Anterior']))
    {
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM flujo WHERE CodFlujo = '$codFlujo' AND CodProcesoSiguiente = '$codProceso'";
    }
    if(isset($_GET['Siguiente']))
    {
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM flujo WHERE CodFlujo = '$codFlujo' AND CodProceso = '$codProcesoSiguiente'";
    }

    include 'vistas/conexion.inc.php';
    
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $codprocesoEnvia = $fila['CodProceso'];
    $archivoEnvia = "vistas/motor.php?codflujo=".$codFlujo."&codproceso=".$codprocesoEnvia;
    echo "$archivoEnvia";
    header("location: ".$archivoEnvia);
 ?>
```

Y es en este lugar donde se presenta el problema, ya que al poner a header la dirección, esta solo me envía a la página 404 del servidor

Pongo las clases de usuario también por si hay algún error:

**user.php**

```
  <?php 
include_once 'conexion.php';

class User extends conexion{

    private $username;
    private $rol;

    public function userExists($user, $pass)
    {
        $query = $this->conectar()->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE User = :user AND Contrasena = :pass');
        $query->execute(['user'=>$user, 'pass'=>$pass]);

        if($query->rowCount())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $query = $this->conectar()->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE User = :user');
        $query->execute(['user'=>$user]);

        foreach ($query as $currentUser) 
        {
            $this->username = $currentUser['User'];
            $this->rol = $currentUser['Rol'];
        }
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getRol()
    {
        return $this->rol;
    }
}

 ?>
```

**user_session.php**

```
    <?php 

class UserSession
{

    public function _construct()
    {
        session_start();
    }

    public function setCurrentUser($user)
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    }

    public function getCurrentUser()
    {
        return $_SESSION['user'];
    }
    public function closeSession()
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }
}

 ?>
```

agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Creo que no es necesario concatenar, intenta esto: header("location: $archivoEnvia");

Comment: No funcionó pero gracias

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema de rutas, ya que cada vez que va avanzando el origen no es el mismo, le recomiendo que al inicio de cada archivo defina una variable constante con la ruta de la raiz del proyecto.

```
define("RUTA_RAIZ", "var/www/..../");
```

y al hacer los includes,

```
include(RUTA_RAIZ."loquesea/motor.php");
```

Con ésto, independientemente de donde realice los includes, el origen para agregar nuevo contenido será siempre la raíz del proyecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funcionó

Comment: @CarlosEduardoOlivaresRodrig, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada.